# What does this error message mean? awk: line 1: missing ) near }

Tags: awk

My code is

```
awk '{if (substr($0,81,1)=="1") print substr($0,1,79)"1"; else  print $0 }' data > collect_irsc_corrected 
awk NF data | awk '{if (substr($0,80,1) == "1") data=substr($0,1,10); if(substr($0,80,1)==""&& substr($0,2,2) != " ") print substr($0,1,15),substr($0,19,10}' > data_irscstation
```

What does this error message for the second code line mean? `awk: line 1: missing ) near }`

---

EDIT: here is the script from above which is producing the error message formatted legibly courtesy of `gawk -o-`:

```
awk '
    {
        if (substr($0, 80, 1) == "1") {
            data = substr($0, 1, 10)
        }
        if (substr($0, 80, 1) == "" && substr($0, 2, 2) != " ") {
            print substr($0, 1, 15), substr($0, 19, 10
        }
    }
'
```

and here is the error message gawk produces trying to execute that code:

```
awk: cmd. line:8:    print substr($0, 1, 15), substr($0, 19, 10
awk: cmd. line:8:                                              ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Hopefully you can see how much easier it is to debug that than when you cram all of your code onto 1 line.

Comment: First of all you could run the two lines separately and see which one is generating the error. That way you can simplify the problem

Comment: Secondly, if that doesn't help and you still need to ask the question, please provide example input that triggers the issue, and corresponding expected output.

Comment: tanks,error in line 2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: AliAsgh, if "_tanks, error in line 2_" means that the second `awk` line is the one causing the problem, please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/751047/edit) to remove the first one as it's irrelevant

Comment: If you don't cram all of your code onto 1 line you'll find it much easier to debug error messages that tell you which line the problem is on.

Comment: By the way, `substr($0,80,1)==""` would be clearer written as `length($0)<80`

Answer (score 3):

Like the error message tells you, you forgot the closing round bracket at the end of your last `awk` script, in the `substr($0,19,10)` function call.